# Why does the Android version of an app require COARSE LOCATION permission to access bluetooth?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, permissions

The react-native app I'm working on uses Bluetooth.  In the IOS version, the only permission(s) that require user confirmation is attemptToTriggerLEPairing.  However, in the Android version of the app, there is a method that contains the following:

```
PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        .then(granted => {
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === true) {
                this.startScan();
                return;
            }
            return PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, {
                    'title': I18n.t('permission_location_title'),
                    'message': I18n.t('permission_location_desc')
                }
            )
                .then(granted => {
                    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === true) {
                        this.startScan();
                    }
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // TODO: error;
        });
```

Why does the Android version require coarse location, but the IOS version does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on the offical [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions)

> Note: LE Beacons are often associated with location. In order to use
>   BluetoothLeScanner, you must request the user's permission by
>   declaring either the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>   permission in your app's manifest file. Without these permissions,
>   scans won't return any results.

Comment: Thank you for including a link to the documentation in your edit!

Answer (score 0):

Along with Android 10, some changes were introduced [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#location-telephony-bluetooth-wifi)

> If your app targets Android 10 or higher, it must have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to use several methods within the Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi Aware, or Bluetooth APIs. The following sections list the affected classes and methods.